# What is a symlink and how to create one?

Tags: php, apache, hosting, symlink

I searched a lot and found no clear definition about symlinking.

I have been working as a php developer for a couple of months and got into situations where I got asked to symlink something. I need a definition of `symlink`, nice and easy to understand. It would be cool to show some examples also.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink.  This is an OS thing. not a PHP/Apache/hosting thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symlink is short for "symbolic link".   It's a special kind of file system file that actually points to another file (which can even be on a different filesystem).

The usual Unix way of creating a symbolic link is:

```
   ln -s SOURCE_FILENAME LINK_NAME
```

If you do a directory listing with `ls`, symbolic links are demarcated with a leading `@` character.

Answer (score 1):

A symbolic link (also called a soft link) essentially references another file.
You can create one on the command line with the command;

```
ln -s target_path link_path
```

Answer (score 1):

bool symlink ( string $target , string $link )
symlink() creates a symbolic link to the existing target with the specified name link.

```
<?php
    $target = 'uploads.php';
    $link = 'uploads';
    symlink($target, $link);

    echo readlink($link);
    ?>
```